# Как достичь 60 fps для примитивного списка?

Tags: android, gpu

Есть `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new RepositoriesAdapter());
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
}
```

`main_activity.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

`RepositoriesAdapter`:

```
public class RepositoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RepositoryItemHolder> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RepositoryItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_repository,
                parent, false);
        return new RepositoryItemHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RepositoryItemHolder itemHolder, int position) {
        itemHolder.textRepositoryName.setText(String.format("Repository %1$s", position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 1000;
    }
}
```

`item_repository.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/text_repository_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="Текст 1"/>
```

Хочу проверить что смартфон отображает список при прокручивании в 60 кадров в секунду с помощью [GPU визуализации](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/inspect-gpu-rendering) в виде столбцов на экране. Тестировал на `Samsung Galaxy A5 2017 (Android 7.0)` и `LG K8 (2017) X240 (Android 6.0)`, на которых столбцы время от времени перескакивают границу в 16мс, но не должны как я понимаю, в основном оранжевый столбец относящийся к `Swap Buffers`, например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему столбики перескакивают границу в 16мс в этом случае?

**P.S.**
Самое странное, что даже если вместо списка добавить обычную кнопку и нажимать её быстро, время от времени оранжевый столбец все равно перескакивает границу в 16мс.

**P.S.S.**
Сейчас стал запускать только релиз сборку. На `Samsung` столбцы почти не перескакивают, возможно связано с тем, что он получил обновление до `Android 8.0`. На `LG` без изменений. Так же посмотрел ещё на `Nokia 3.1` с `Android 8.0` - не перескакивают.

Интересно для начала как ведет себя график на других слабых девайсах.

Ссылка на репозиторий для быстрого запуска:
https://github.com/iamtihonov/TestList

Comment: Попробуйте репозиторий выложить куда-то типа GitHub - чтобы можно было в пару кликов его получить и запустить. Возможно, так будет проще кому-то на ваш вопрос ответить)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Хорошая идея

Comment: У вас в репозиторий ключ релизный улетел вмете с паролем) И apk тоже. Так и планировалось? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да это тестовый ключ. Мне его не жалко)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так и статистика fps стала заметно лучше

---

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new RepositoriesAdapter(MainActivity.this));
```

---

```
Context context;

RepositoriesAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        array[i] = "Repository " + (i + 1);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RepositoryItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_repository,
            parent, false);
    return new RepositoryItemHolder(itemView);
}
```

в целом считаю что контекст не стоит часто дергать (слишком "дорогая" операция).

Comment: *слишком "дорогая" операция* - это вы про `getContext()`? Это же обычный геттер к приватному полю?! Тогда уж инфлейтер лучше получить в конструкторе - вызов `getSystemService()` по-любому дороже геттера.